# How do I make nested items in combobox wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, grouping, hierarchical

I work in C# and I'm trying to find a solution to creating a "Hierarchical Combobox", as iv'e searched for hours around the internet and found no real solution to this problem.

The closest iv'e reached is working with normal wpf combobox using group descriptions, but still, it is not good enough for me and I no where to advance on my own.

The things i need the controller to achieve:

- Each item can have sub items, if there are no sub-items, the item can be select-able, if there are sub-items, only the sub-items that don't have sub-items recursively are select-able .
- The popup of the combo box will finally show all the items indented, just as a normal tree view

in the end, it should look like this:

---

**example:**

```
Folder
   Selectable Item
   Folder
       Selectable Item
       Selectable Item
   Selectable Item
```

---

- as you see folder's themselves are not supposed to be selectable.

What I got so far you can see in the next article: http://www.jarloo.com/wpf-combobox-with-groupings/

P.S: I should say that I realize the work looks like it should defintly should be done in a TreeView, problem is, I already tested that and tree view does not have combobox logics with selectable items, etc...

TLDR: Basically I want an Hierarchical Combobox, That combobox should have a tree view inside of it, with only non-parents nodes select-able.

Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure I understand.. you want each node in the "tree" let's call it to be a `ComboBox`? What whould that ComboBox display?

Comment: Basicly I want an Hierarchical Combobox, That combobox should have a tree view inside of it, with only non-parents nodes selectable.

Comment: I still don't get why you insist on ComboBox. Sounds like a classic `TreeView` where the user can only select the leafs. You can have the TreeView appear on a button click or some other operation to avoid displaying it all the time but it still doesn't sound like a `ComboBox` to me ...

Comment: How would you design such a TreeView if I may ask?

Answer (score 0):

Like I said in the comment section, I don't see how a `ComboBox` is handy in your situation.

Here is an example of how to achieve such a thing using `TreeView`

Using [MSDN Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd759035%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), Create a class that represents a node in your `TreeView`

```
public class Path
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsLeaf { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Path> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Create an [HierarchicalDataTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate.aspx)s to present it

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="LeafTemplate" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
      <TextBlock FontStyle="Italic" Text="{Binding Name}"  />
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="FolderTemplate" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource LeafTemplate}">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Make a `TreeView` that uses it, and denies focus for paths that are not leafs

```
<TreeView Width="400"  Height="300" ItemsSource="{Binding Paths}" 
          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource FolderTemplate}" x:Name="myTreeView">
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
           <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="{Binding IsLeaf}"/>
        </Style>
    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
</TreeView>
```

If you want to test this example you can use the following code for the `Paths` fill

```
Paths = new ObservableCollection<Path>();
var p1 = new Path { Name = "Folder 1", IsLeaf = false , Children = new ObservableCollection<Path>() };
var p11 = new Path { Name = "Item 1-1", IsLeaf = true, Children = new ObservableCollection<Path>() };
var p12 = new Path { Name = "Item 1-2", IsLeaf = true, Children = new ObservableCollection<Path>() };
var p13 = new Path { Name = "Folder 1-3", IsLeaf = false, Children = new ObservableCollection<Path>() };
var p131 = new Path { Name = "Item 1-3-1", IsLeaf = true, Children = new ObservableCollection<Path>() };

// Build path's
p13.Children.Add(p131);
p1.Children.Add(p11);
p1.Children.Add(p12);
p1.Children.Add(p13);
Paths.Add(p1);
```

You can off course control his visibilty and make it appear whenever you like, for example when a button get's clicked, for example:

```
        <ToggleButton Content="Select Item" x:Name="treeViewVisible"/>
        <TreeView Width="400"  Height="300" ItemsSource="{Binding Paths}"
                  Visibility="{Binding ElementName=treeViewVisible, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource boolToVisibilityConverter}}" .... />
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, will try to use it and will report back.